# Using Atomics and Float32Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, atomic, typed-arrays

The Atomics.store/load methods (and others? didn't look) do not support Float32Array.
I read that this is to be consistent with the fact that it also doesn't support Float64Array for compatibility reasons (some computers don't support it).

Aside from the fact that I think this is stupid, does this also mean I must cast every float I want to use into an unsigned int?

Not only will this result in ugly code, it will also make it slower.

E.g.:

```
let a = new Float32Array(1); // Want the result here

Atomics.store(a, 0, 0.5); // Oops, can't use Float32Array

let b = new Float32Array(1); // Want the result here

let uint = new Uint32Array(1);
let float = new Float32Array(uint.buffer);

float[0] = 0.5;

Atomics.store(b, 0, uint[0]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you discovered, the Atomics methods [doesn't support floating point values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/store) as argument:

> Atomics.store(typedArray, index, value)
>
> typedArray
>       A shared **integer** typed array. One of Int8Array, Uint8Array, Int16Array, Uint16Array, Int32Array,
>       or Uint32Array.

You can can read the IEEE754 representation as integer from the underlying buffer as you do in the example code you posted

```js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);         // common buffer
var float32 = new Float32Array(buffer);  // floating point
var uint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);    // IEEE754 representation

float32[0] = 0.5;
console.log("0x" + uint32[0].toString(16));

uint32[0] = 0x3f000000;   /// IEEE754 32-bit representation of 0.5
console.log(float32[0]);
```

or you can use *fixed numbers* if the accuracy isn't important. The accuracy is of course determined by the magnitude.

Scale up when storing:

```
Atomics.store(a, 0, Math.round(0.5 * 100)); // 0.5 -> 50 (max two decimals with 100)
```

read back and scale down:

```
value = Atomics.load(a, 0) * 0.01;          // 50 -> 0.5
```

Answer (score -2):

The other answer didn't help me much and it took awhile for me to figure out a solution, but here's how I solved the same issue:

```
var data = new SharedArrayBuffer(LEN * 8);
var data_float = new Float32Array(data);
var data_int = new Uint32Array(data);
data_float[0] = 2.3; //some pre-existing data

var tmp = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var tmp_float = new Float32Array(tmp);
var tmp_int = new Uint32Array(tmp);

tmp_int[0] = Atomics.load(data_int, 0);
tmp_float[0] += 1.1; //some math
Atomics.store(data_int, 0, tmp_int[0]);

console.log(data_float[0]);
```